# Make each div element fit browser window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to design a webpage where each div element fits the browser window.
Here's what I have right now:
http://jsfiddle.net/E9HER/

What I need to do is to have each of those red-bordered containers to vertically fit the browser window (for heights greater than 500px).

```
<div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="WhoWeAre"><a name="WhoWeAre">Who we are</a></div>
    <div class="WhatWeDo"><a name="WhatWeDo">What we do</a></div>
    <div class="OurWork"><a name="OurWork">Our work</a></div>
    <div class="Contact"><a name="Contact">Contact</a></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine for me. What browser are you using? (I'm on Chrome.)

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
    .wrapper {min-height:500px;
     height:100%;}

   .contentcontainer {
   height:85%;
   min-height:500px}
```

apply the contentcontainer properties to the containing divs as well...

You will have to play around with the % to come to a proper height.

This will scale the divs to the browser window, but will set it to 500px for windows below that...

Comment: For some reason, it isn't working. Here is an updated jsfiddle, with the changes you recommended
http://jsfiddle.net/MxxZd/

Comment: that's because the Js fiddle window makes it lower than 500px, I removed the `min-height:500px` and now it works fine, I tried the same code on a seperate document at normal window sizes and it worked there as well. here's a fiddle without `min-height` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDsouza/Yfwet/)